# What files do C# programs execute first?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to understand a massive application that was written by other developers.

I want to know, of all these `.cs` files, which one would be executed first, so I know how to trace through and set breakpoints.

There are about 25 of these `.cs` files, but I'm not sure where to start. Which one would be executed first?

Comment: That depends if it's windows forms, wpf, console or web-server.

Comment: @spender windows forms

Comment: Start with `static void Main()`

Comment: @IvanStoev and in which file would that be in? i'm assuming it would somehow correspond to the name space or project name or something?

Comment: Actually it's not fixed. Usually is called `Program.cs`. But you can always search in files for the above string.

Comment: CTRL + F > change combobox that poped to "entire solution" and type in "void Main()". Win.

Comment: @polisha989 using the search built in to the Solution Explorer would be better, then it would only check method and class names for `Main`

Comment: @IvanStoev you're right. I found `Program.cs` and it looks like that's it. Thank-you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can immediately "step into" the executing code by using the Debug menu or pressing F11. This will "break" at the first executable line of code

Comment: Oh wow. I have been using Visual Studio for years and never knew you could just hit F11 do a step in-to to start it. I have always done the right click on the project, debug->Step in to new instance.

Comment: +1 to @ScottChamberlain, though I'm worse. When accidentally hitting it, I get a bit mad, stop the debugging and go to debug with `F5`. This is a really useful feature.

Comment: I can't say it's one of the most useful features of Visual Studio and to be honest I only know it exists because I've pressed it my mistake a few times 

Comment: or for more forgetful people like me you can show the debug toolbar from `View` > `Toobars` > `Debug` and Step Into from there

Answer (score 1):

For most .NET-based applications, from console programs to ASP.NET Core web sites, the so-called **entry-point** is the method `Main` in Program.cs, this includes webforms.

`Main` is *the* first method you should look for if you don't know where the entry-point for a program is, regardless of language. It has been around since the dawn of programming and lived across multiple programming paradigms.

**From wikipedia:**

> In many programming languages, the `main` function is where a program starts its execution. It is responsible for the high-level organization of the program's functionality, and typically has access to the command arguments given to the program when it was executed.

Comment: Wikipedia is not considered very reliable source as it can be edited by anyone. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx

Comment: I took the quote from Wikipedia because I considered it accurate myself, it was to describe `main` in the abstract, not for C# in particular. Also, it's not like every answer on SO links to a reliable source. There are plenty of accepted and popular answers that link to no sources at all. What's with that?

Answer (score 0):

In all cases where your application is executed as a standalone application (vs where it is executed by another application, like asp.net being executed by IIS) then it starts in Main static method. This has nothing to do with in what "file" the function resides and is the same for all the application types other posts mentioned (wpf winform console etc).

If you want to have multiple functions named Main that could match the entry point you will need to speficy which one to use in the compiler settings : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3eht538.aspx