# Why does the Main(string[] args) function always execute first , ie., before any other function present in the code

Tags: c#

I have started learning c#, and it is also my first programming language.
While doing functions, i noticed that all functions are called through the 
Main(string[] args) function.

Like, in this code, taken from Microsoft Docs, The Main(string[] args) function calls first.
Does this function have something special?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
       var (_, _, _, pop1, _, pop2) = QueryCityDataForYears("New York City", 1960, 2010);

       Console.WriteLine($"Population change, 1960 to 2010: {pop2 - pop1:N0}");
   }

   private static (string, double, int, int, int, int) QueryCityDataForYears(string name, int year1, int year2)
   {
      int population1 = 0, population2 = 0;
      double area = 0;

      if (name == "New York City") {
         area = 468.48; 
         if (year1 == 1960) {
            population1 = 7781984;
         }
         if (year2 == 2010) {
            population2 = 8175133;
         }
      return (name, area, year1, population1, year2, population2);
      }

      return ("", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
   }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39428107/34092 https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/156336/why-a-static-main-method-in-java-and-c-rather-than-a-constructor

Comment: Its the entry point in console applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When any program starts its execution OS starts execution of the method from the main method. Let me explain in a lay man's term, There is a house and you want to enter to visit your friend. What would you do? You will look for the entrance gate to enter the house :). So here is main function is just the entrance gate which OS launch at start when the execution of a program get started.

We can also send command line parameters into main method when we execute java program through cmd.

Example Program

```
class cmd
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    for(int i=0;i< args.length;i++)
    {
    System.out.println(args[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Execute this program like

> Execute this program as java cmd 10 20 30

Output:

> 10
>
> 20
>
> 30

[image]

Comment: That's what I want to know, what is so special with the Main(string[] args)  function! Is it something to with its parameter?

Comment: @Koroshiya when we run program we can send command line parameters into main method into args array, I updated my answer explaining command line parameters you can check.

Comment: which IDE you use? I will give example according to it

Comment: Okay so as I described in my answer, the basic purpose of the string[] args, is to send command line parameters when you execute your program. And here you can find out the way how to send values into this "args" parameter in Visual Studio when you execute your program.
https://dailydotnettips.com/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-using-visual-studio/

Comment: Let me know if its still not clear, or you have any other question, If it works please upvote & accept my answer. thanks.

Comment: So, if I were to use a really primitive IDE, then would I still be able to create a function like Main(string[] args?

Comment: Yes thats the method which should be written in your java Class, each IDE/Compiler starts its execution through the Main method, You can pass the values in the "args" array at the time of execution.. its all irrespective of the IDE, it doesn't matter whatever the IDE you are using. And one more thing, this "args" is just a variable name for your string array, you can change its name.

Comment: @AsadAliChoudhary Thank you, I think I get it